# CSS / HTML: Unable to change the height of divs

Tags: html, css

Code ready to edit in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkdjetkq/1/

I am in the process of setting up a website advertising a region for people to visit as a task for myself.

I have spent some time attempting to place all I have done so far all on one page. I wish for there to be no scrollbars, I do not want to make the scrollbars invisible or so forth, I mean have the web page fit on one page of the browser without the user having the need to scroll for aesthetic purposes.

I have played around with the height of divs along with a number of other things in an attempt to achieve my desired result but with no success unfortunately. Changing the height of divs using percentages does not do anything for me. What would I be required to change regarding my code in order to achieve this?

CSS:

```
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    }

    body {
        wdith: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #container {
        wdith: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #navigation {
        color: white;
        background-color: #292526;
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
    }

    #navigationLeft {
        width: 24.5%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    #navigationRight {
        width: 74.5%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #navigation ul {
        float: right;
    }

    #navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
        font-size: 100%;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   

    #banner {
        line-height: 0;
        height: 70%;
    }

    #cliffPic {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70%;
    }

    #footer {
        color: white;
        background-color: #181818 ;
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="navigation">
        <div id="navigationLeft">
            <a href="#">Visit Clare Ireland</a>
        </div><!--

        --><div id="navigationRight">
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="#">Home |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maps |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Appartments |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Attractions |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Essentials |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Bars & Clubs |</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Transport</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>

    <div id="banner">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VsIRZNZ.jpg" alt="The Cliffs of Moher" id="cliffPic"/> 
    </div>

  <div id="footer">
        <p>Placeholder Text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which section are you trying to get to a percentage height?

Comment: I would like to make the web page fit on one's desktop screen without having the need to scroll down. For example, the height of the div "navigation" could be 20%, the height of the div "banner" containing the image could be 70% and the height of the div "footer" could be 10%.

Comment: What you just said is the exact answer to your question. The only place you specified a height is in the content - you'll need to specify one for the header and footer too.

And size is always relative to the nearest positioned ancestor. This means the nearest ancestor with `position: relative` or `position:absolute`.

Comment: You have typos in your CSS to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Set your html height to 100% `html {height: 100%}`

Set your box-sizing to border-box `* {box-sizing: border-box}` This is to make sure that your padding on the elements doesn't add on to the width/height, rather becomes part of the width/height.

Set your navigation to 20% height `#navigation {height: 20%}`

Set your banner to 70% height `#banner {height: 70%}`

Set your footer to 10% height `#footer {height: 10%}`

You'll notice that your image stretches, an easy way to fix this is to set it as a background within that div and set background-size to cover `#banner {background: <background>; background-size: cover}`

Basically, you need the immediate parent element of a child element to have a set height or the child element will not obey percentage heights, and yes this will need to be traversed all the way back to the first set height ancestor. In this case you had everything set correctly, just needed the 100% height on the html element.

Answer (score 0):

throw `html { overflow-y: hidden; }` in the stylesheet if you want to manipulate it to hide the scroll bar while the height is 100%. Be warned, if you exceed the 100% it will not be visible at all even with scrolling. So make sure you use the correct media-queries for responsiveness

Comment: What I'm looking to do is have web page fit one's desktop screen without having the need to scroll down rather than hiding the ability to scroll down.

Comment: Have you looked at [Bootstrap's responsive code](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) for handling grids and responsive websites? seperately, you are using 100% for the content which is fluid, as long as everything else is a percentage in that hierarchy it should scale correctly to the size of the container. e.g. make the width and height of the main image a percentage of the screen rather than a solid width x height

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed css:

1) You couldn't set the height because the html tag wans't styled to have a 100% width and height. To control the height of elements, always specify that the html tag (the outermost container of the html document) and body tag have a height of 100%.

2) Since the size of the menu will change in different screen sizes, you cannot use a fixed height ratio for any of the elements. To fix that, I added the css flexbox to your code, which ensures that the menu, banner and footer takeup the remaining space in the page and do not overflow.

```
    body,td,th {
        font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
    }

    body, html {
        wdith: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #container {
        wdith: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction:column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    #navigation {
        color: white;
        background-color: #292526;
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
    }

    #navigationLeft {
        width: 24.5%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 150%;
    }

    #navigationRight {
        width: 74.5%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #navigation ul {
        float: right;
    }

    #navigation ul li {
        display: inline;
    }

    #navigation a {
        font-size: 100%;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }   

    #banner {
        line-height: 0;-webkit-flex: 1; flex: 1;
    }

    #cliffPic {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #footer {
        color: white;
        background-color: #181818 ;
        width: 99%;
        padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: I've added everything that you need to the code above :)